# Error: "the application completed without reading the entire request body" Angular/C#

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I have an error sending a `string` in my Angular service.

I tried to run my stored procedure when sending the string with Postman and everything works fine.

**Postman:**
[image]
[image]

However, when I send the string through my service it does not work.

**user.service.ts:**

```
addUser(user: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<string>('/api/user/AddUser', user)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

**Console error:**

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thwES.png)
>         Request finished in 11.3875ms 400 application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
>         Connection id "0HLL95U87FBQE", Request id "0HLL95U87FBQE:00000003": the application completed without reading
>   the entire request body.

**Browser error:**

[image]

So I do not really know what the API really gets, because the result it expects must be a string of characters.

**UserController C#:**

```
[HttpPost]
public User AddUser([FromBody]string user)
{
  return objUser.AddUser(user);
}
```

If you have a solution to my problem, I'm interested.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** 
By modifying my service like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
})

addUser(user: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<User>('/api/user/AddUser', user.toString(), httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

I get this new error:
*Knowing that A is the first letter of the first name in the string.*

[image]

Comment: You might want to consider adding a swagger implementation to the API if you have access. Will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any code that affects this error, the only point comes into mind is a string or JSON object need to be stringified which is differs from the Postman. SO it's better to always stringify the request body before passing it to API.

Try this:

```
addUser(user: string): Observable<any> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })

  var userName = JSON.stringify(user);  // This

  return this.http.post<user>('/api/user/AddUser', userName, httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to set the content-type in the http header to be the same as you have set in Postman and to actually send JSON. Also you want the post to return a user object so your userservice.ts would be something like this:

```
addUser(user: string): Observable<any> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
  return this.http.post<user>('/api/user/AddUser', JSON.stringify(user), httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Comment: `error: "": ["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 1, position 1."]` I get this error now instead of `"The input was not valid."`

Knowing that A is the first letter of the first name in the string.